# kdeconncted connections?

Tags: 18.04, netstat, kde-connect

I have a number of Ubuntu Bionic hosts on a network. I noticed a connection between two of them (in netstat) that showed a connection between two of the hosts.

In syslog, I see that it's seeking out other BIONIC hosts and making connections before trying to load a number of plugins:

```
Aug 19 16:35:31 BIONIC-SHIPPING kdeconnectd.desktop[15074]: kdeconnect.core: It is a new device "student@BIONIC-student"
Aug 19 16:35:31 BIONIC-SHIPPING kdeconnectd.desktop[15074]: kdeconnect.core: Not loading plugin "kdeconnect_findmyphone" because device doesn't support it
Aug 19 16:35:31 BIONIC-SHIPPING kdeconnectd.desktop[15074]: kdeconnect.core: Not loading plugin "kdeconnect_telephony" because device doesn't support it
Aug 19 16:35:31 BIONIC-SHIPPING kdeconnectd.desktop[15074]: kdeconnect.core: Not loading plugin "kdeconnect_mpriscontrol" because device doesn't support it
Aug 19 16:35:31 BIONIC-SHIPPING kdeconnectd.desktop[15074]: kdeconnect.core: Not loading plugin "kdeconnect_pausemusic" because device doesn't support it
Aug 19 16:35:31 BIONIC-SHIPPING kdeconnectd.desktop[15074]: kdeconnect.core: Not loading plugin "kdeconnect_runcommand" because device doesn't support it
Aug 19 16:35:31 BIONIC-SHIPPING kdeconnectd.desktop[15074]: kdeconnect.core: Not loading plugin "kdeconnect_battery" because device doesn't support it
Aug 19 16:35:31 BIONIC-SHIPPING kdeconnectd.desktop[15074]: kdeconnect.core: Not loading plugin "kdeconnect_sftp" because device doesn't support it
```

1. What is happening here?
2. Is there some automatic discovery happening?
3. What would be the logic behind this implementation? Is this related to desktop sharing (VNC)?
4. What kind of attack surface is being exposed by that daemon?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is just a normal scan it performs of a network to find other KDE connect devices. Perhaps the reason it mistakes the desktops for phones is that the KDE programmers were trying to make it possible to find KDE phones running (k)ubuntu rather than the stock android kernel. I'm pretty sure this is the case for me as well because my Samsung phone with KDE connect shows up as an option instantly, so a scan must be occurring. On the topic of attack vectors, it may be possible for a desktop to run a virtual KDE phone and expose its network interface to that which would be used on the laptop, but from there, you would need to authenticate the device from yours, so the attack would probably only yield what was delivered in the communication packets. I'm sorry I didn't answer your questions sequentially, but I, too am unsure of the specifics of this situation.